# How to get and set the Security info of file in NTFS partition?

Tags: linux, ntfs

In Linux, how to get/set the Security info of file in NTFS partition?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is looking at the source code of ntfsprogs, and particularly of the `ntfsinfo` utility, which seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am checking the ntfsinfo. Another question: is there same features in ntfs-3g?

Comment: They are made by the same group. And I don't think ntfs-3g really does that: the Windows file permission model is very different from the traditional Unix, and even POSIX ACLs, file permission model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing but because the security system is so different between NT and Linux (and other Unixes) probably the best format you'll be able to get with full fidelity is the raw binary version of the security descriptor on a file. Anything else would be an inexact translation to POSIX ACLs or classic Unix security.

The format stored on disk will be a [self-relative security descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374807(v=vs.85).aspx) (one binary blob), up to 64k. Note that NTFS keeps a single copy of each unique security descriptor in a special $SECURITY file in the root directory; files point back to the shared entry in there. This is done because most of the time all the files in a directory or a tree will all have identical SDs and it's a waste of space to store 5000 copies of the same data. The filesystem driver used to read/update NTFS security would need to take that into account.